Expo permissions not working on development build but works on expo go
I am trying to access ios permissions using expo it works on expo go ios simulator and a real device but doesnt work on development build. I researched and i think it is because i dont have an apple developer membership account but i am not a 100% sure. Here is my error
WARN  The native view manager required by name (ExpoCamera) from NativeViewManagerAdapter isn't exported by expo-modules-core. Views of this type may not render correctly. Exported view managers: [RNCSafeAreaProvider, ExpoLinearGradient].
ERROR  Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoCamera', js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I am trying to access camera, microphone and media gallery and below is the code on how i handled it


import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet, Alert, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


const ProfilePicture: React.FC<{ navigation: any }> = ({ navigation }) => {
  interface cameraStates {
    hasCameraPermission : boolean | null,
    profileImage: string | null
  }

  const [states, setStates] = useState<cameraStates>({
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    profileImage: null
  })
  const cameraRef = useRef<Camera>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setStates({...states, hasCameraPermission : status === 'granted'});
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleTakePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
      setStates({...states, profileImage: photo.uri});
    }
  };

  const handleChooseFromGallery = async () => {
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      Alert.alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
      return;
    }
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });
    if (!result.canceled && result.assets) {
      setStates({...states, profileImage: result.assets[0].uri});
    }
  };

  const handleRemoveImage = () => {
    setStates({...states, profileImage: null});
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    if (states.profileImage) {
      navigation.navigate("ConnectContact");
    }
  };

  if (states.hasCameraPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (states.hasCameraPermission) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }



I have also included the couple information in my info.plist
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera.</string>
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your contacts</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use the microphone</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.</string>

Also included these in my app.json
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-camera",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera."
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-media-library",
        {
          "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos.",
        "savePhotosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos.",
        "isAccessMediaLocationEnabled": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.iseoluwa411.mySocialMediaApp",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "This app requires access to the photo library to use photos for display pictures.",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app requires access to the camera to take photos for display pictures."
      }

Please how can this error be fixed in development mode. Works perfectly well in expo go
